# Is it possible to have multiple users (through excel addin) on a single bloomberg terminal?

Tags: bloomberg

I have a bloomberg terminal where users have to keep switching every time someone needs some information. So i would like to know (either through LAN or remotely),  is it possible to pull data from the bloomberg from other computers? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bloomberg Professional service (commonly referred to as a 'terminal') is a one-user-at-a-time product. As a result, it does not provide network connectivity at all; its API endpoint is only accessible locally on the machine where the software is running and the user is logged in.

In addition, the license agreement for the product restricts the usage of data obtained through it; you should check with your Bloomberg account manager to determine whether your usage of the product fits with the license terms, or whether you would benefit from another Bloomberg product.